# Remove the space of ending element?

Tags: c#, xml

Currently I am using XML to store many data and when creating those XML files I would like to reduce it is size to the minimum I can.

How could I override the XmlWriter function (WriteEndElement) so instead of saving it like:

```
<thisElement someAttribute="blabla" />
```

It will be saved like:

```
<thisElement someAttribute="blabla"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to find a way to acomplish this by using:

```
public override void WriteEndElement()
```

But I can't the the current WriteEndElement function to know what I have to change on it and if it is even possible.

Comment: Standard compression won't work?  If not I'll come up with an answer.

Comment: The application that will be using the xml is not made by us and we already requested changes to it but it is not schedule to change any time soon so we are doing what we can to minimise it :( and the change of that space is one of them there are files with million entries. Files with 200mb, 300mb some more but that is the currently average.

Comment: I know this is a complete hack idea, but you could string replace it. put the whole file in a string, `strXML`. run `strXML.Replace("\" />", "\"/>")` on it. then `XElement.Parse(strXML)`.

Comment: @jb I currently do something similar but I was looking for a solution that would allow me to change it when I am generating the file that would be for me the best since I would do it just once hence why I was looking for a way to do this by changing the WriteEndElement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible without rewriting significant portions of code.  The space is hardcoded in the internal classes and not configurable.

e.g., Code snippet of the internal `XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteEndElement()` method.

```
internal override void WriteEndElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
{
    // snip...
    else
    {
        this.bufPos--;
        this.bufChars[this.bufPos++] = ' '; // the space is hard coded
        this.bufChars[this.bufPos++] = '/';
        this.bufChars[this.bufPos++] = '>';
    }
}
```

Some options that you have that I can think of are to parse the outputted XML to search for the closing tags to remove the space manually, implement your own XML writer so it doesn't include this space, or write a wrapper class to use reflection to modify the internal buffers when the end element is written.

---

Here's an extension method which could do that.  Just be warned, this is not portable.  Nor is it guaranteed to work for all cases though it seems to work for simple cases.  I don't think what is done here would corrupt the state of the writer but, **use at your own risk**.

```
public static class XmlWriterExtensions
{
    private static readonly Func<XmlWriter, object> get_writer;
    private static readonly Func<object, char[]> get_bufChars;
    private static readonly Func<object, int> get_bufPos;
    private static readonly Action<object, int> set_bufPos;

    static XmlWriterExtensions()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(XmlWriter));
        var xmlWellFormedWriterType = asm.GetType("System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter");
        var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var writerField = xmlWellFormedWriterType.GetField("writer", flags);
        get_writer = w => writerField.GetValue(w);
        var xmlEncodedRawTextWriterType = asm.GetType("System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter");
        var bufCharsField = xmlEncodedRawTextWriterType.GetField("bufChars", flags);
        var bufPosField = xmlEncodedRawTextWriterType.GetField("bufPos", flags);
        get_bufChars = w => (char[])bufCharsField.GetValue(w);
        get_bufPos = w => (int)bufPosField.GetValue(w);
        set_bufPos = (w, i) => bufPosField.SetValue(w, i);

    }

    public static void TrimElementEnd(this XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var internalWriter = get_writer(writer);
        char[] bufChars = get_bufChars(internalWriter);
        int bufPos = get_bufPos(internalWriter);
        if (bufPos > 3 && bufChars[bufPos - 3] == ' ' && bufChars[bufPos - 2] == '/' && bufChars[bufPos - 1] == '>')
        {
            bufChars[bufPos - 3] = '/';
            bufChars[bufPos - 2] = '>';
            bufPos--;
            set_bufPos(internalWriter, bufPos);
        }
    }
}

// usage:
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Foo");
    writer.WriteElementString("Bar", null);
    writer.TrimElementEnd();
    writer.WriteElementString("Baz", null);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Foo><Bar/><Baz /></Foo>
```

Comment: This is what I was currently doing `parse the outputted XML to search for the closing tags to remove the space`

Comment: @Guapo: Stay tuned, I'll work on trying to write up the last option.  It's possible but very hackish.

Comment: @Jeff I am looking forward to it would be a bless to have it implemented.

Comment: @Guapo: Update doing it is as an extension method.  As long as you are ending the elements yourself by calling `WriteEndElement()`, this should work good enough.

Comment: Please don't show dissembled proprietary code on a public forum like SO, since people reading this are not allowed to contribute to ie. Mono http://mono-project.com/Contributing

Comment: @Pauli: Removed.  Though I didn't think it was a big deal since the framework source had been available since 2008 and the code was just here to illustrate my point.  It's not like it was exposing an algorithm, it's just writing to a buffer.

Comment: the problem is not that the source is not publicly available... but implementing something like Mono you are NOT ALLOWED to copy the code from Microsoft. Its released under a read-only license, so creating Mono you have to recreate the same behavior but writing code from scratch. Quote *In general, be careful when you are implementing free software and you have access to proprietary code. We need to make sure that we are not using someone else's copyrighted code accidentally.*